# problem with creating .exe file in python why it gets too big

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, pyinstaller, exe

I'm making archives to .exe using `pyinstaller`, but I have a big problem, every time I create a file, its size multiplies, it seems that it is multiplying the libraries, does anyone know how to solve it?

```
1° file size: 7mb 
2° file size: 52mb
3° file size: 104mb
4° file size: 207mb
5° file size: 414mb
6° file size: 828mb
7° file size: 1.656mb
8° file size: 3.312mb
```

I tried to rename the files, deleted `%tmp%` files

Answer (score 0):

## You can try [AutoPyToExe](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/)

**with python's [virtual environment plugin](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/)**

follow these commands:

1. Install, Create and Activate Virtual Environment:

> python -m pip install virtualenv

> python -m venv example_env

> example_env/Scripts/activate

2. Install AutoPyToExe:

> (example_env) python -m pip install auto-py-to-exe

3. To run AutoPyToExe, just write this command in Command Prompt or Terminal:

> (example_env) auto-py-to-exe

4. **Important:** ***Installing only those modules in the virtual environment which are required by the project.***
5. Working with virtualenv in python:

- Activate virtual environment using this command:

  **Linux**: <path_to_virtual_env>\bin\activate

  **Windows**: <path_to_virtual_env>\Scripts\activate
- Deactivate virtual environment using this command:

  **deactivate**

Answer (score 0):

I did the above but it didn't work...
a solution I found for the problem is to create an .exe file .. I move it from the folder (to any other) I delete the "dist" and "build" folders that were created, then I create the other executable file...